# How to pass response from external api to dialog in watson conversation?

Tags: python, ibm-watson, watson, watson-conversation

I'm building a weather bot using watson conversation api.

Whenever a user sends 'what is the weather of '. I get back a response with intents and entities. Now I make a call to a weather api and get a response. How do I pass this weather response back to watson dialog to be displayed?

I think that I have to send the response through context object, but how do I make the call to conversation api to pass the response?

I'm using python api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the API Referecence from IBM official document, show one example to how send message inside Watson Conversation Service.

Check this example:

```
import json
from watson_developer_cloud import ConversationV1

conversation = ConversationV1(
  username='{username}',
  password='{password}',
  version='2017-04-21'
)

# Replace with the context obtained from the initial request
context = {}

workspace_id = '25dfa8a0-0263-471b-8980-317e68c30488'

response = conversation.message(
  workspace_id=workspace_id,
  message_input={'text': 'Turn on the lights'},
  context=context
)

print(json.dumps(response, indent=2))
```

In this case, to send the message from user, you can use `message_input`, and to send message like Watson, you can use `output`.
If your parameter is set to `response`, for example, you can use:

```
#Get response from Watson Conversation
responseFromWatson = conversation.message(
    workspace_id=WORKSPACE_ID,
    message_input={'text': command},
    context=context
)
```

See one official example code from [IBM Developers](https://gist.github.com/zwalchuk/73188198b386a996da25a6f091ff82b4#file-starterbot-py-L221):

```
if intent == "schedule":
            response = "Here are your upcoming events: "
            attachments = calendarUsage(user, intent)
        elif intent == "free_time":
            response = calendarUsage(user, intent)
        else:
            response = responseFromWatson['output']['text'][0] //THIS SEND THE MESSAGE TO USER

    slack_client.api_call("chat.postMessage", as_user=True, channel=channel, text=response,
                      attachments=attachments)
```

Use this to send:

```
response = responseFromWatson['output']['text'][0];
 if intent == "timeWeather":
        response = "The Weather today is: " +yourReturnWeather
```

Tutorial from IBM Developer for this project [here](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/watson/2016/10/easy-slack-integration-watson-conversation/).

This example will integrate with Slack, but you can see one good example to did what you want in this [project](https://gist.github.com/zwalchuk/73188198b386a996da25a6f091ff82b4#file-starterbot-py).

See [official documentation](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/?python#send_message).